# Can keywords in the URL path be separated by commas for Google?

Tags: seo, google, url, keywords, url-parameters

As we know, keywords in the URL are helpful with your SEO, for example, `/keyword1-keyword2`, or `keyword1_keyword2`. We know that Google is able to identify the two keywords.

However, what if it was more like, `/url=keyword1,keyword2` ?

Would they also be read by Google?

Comment: Underscores are **NOT** keyword separators in the URL for Google.  It is a long standing issue that Google *will not* identify they keywords if you use an underscore.

Comment: Stuffing keywords in the URL is unlikely to help SEO unless it enhances usabality.   See: [Are keywords in URLs good SEO or needlessly redundant?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/are-keywords-in-urls-good-seo-or-needlessly-redundant)

Comment: No years ago Matt Cutts announced that underscores are now keyword separators

Comment: Matt Cutts has never said that.   The latest video I can find https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQcSFsQyct8 from 2011 still says: "we join on underscore and separate on dash."   Google has no plans to change that.  Matt Cutts also explains it in a blog post from 2005: [Dashes vs Underscores](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores)

Comment: I am pretty sure he did, but if he didnt then someone else from Google announced it. But, cant think of anyone else who it could have been, so it  must have been Cutts.

Comment: John Mueller was quoted here https://www.seroundtable.com/google-doesnt-care-about-underscores-vs-dashes-in-urls-22180.html saying that underscores vs dashes doesn't matter.   I think that he is saying that the effect of keywords in URLs is so small that it isn't something worth worrying about.

Comment: For usability, hyphens are much easier for users to type (and remember) than underscores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser will encode input, according to the character-set used in your page.

I personally avoid `,` in url structure, because of encoding. It's `%2C`.

So your url would be like `/url=keyword1%2Ckeyword2`.

Commas are allowed in the filename part of a URL, but are reserved characters in the domain.

* From the [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

> 2.2. Reserved Characters
>
> Many URI include components consisting of or delimited by, certain
>      special characters.  These characters are called "reserved", since
>      their usage within the URI component is limited to their reserved
>      purpose.  If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
>      reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
>      forming the URI.
>
> ```
>  reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
>                 "$" | ","
> ```
>
> The "reserved" syntax class above refers to those characters that are
>      allowed within a URI, but which may not be allowed within a
>      particular component of the generic URI syntax

While it's definitely possible to use commas in URLs, it's not a widely used practice, nor is it recommended.

Further reading: https://www.searchenginenews.com/sample/content/are-you-using-commas-in-your-urls-heres-what-you-need-to-know

Comment: Nice answer. Have never seen commas in url in my 10 years of online life.

Comment: You don’t have to percent-encode `,` in the URI path ([see list of allowed characters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/91211/17633)).

Answer (score 3):

Commas are not typically used in URLs and are not recommended. You should stick to using either underscores or hyphens/dashes. That being said, Google recommends hyphens/dashes, so I would go with that: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/76329?hl=en

Comment: The question was not "Should I put commas in my URL's?" It is a sensible question to ask, if you are supporting a legacy site that happens to have commas in URLs. And this doesn't answer the question at all.